# How to check if a Conn is active without sending/receiving data?

Tags: go

In Go/Golang, once a connection object (Conn) is created with the following code:

```
conn, err := net.Dial("tcp","33.33.33.33:444")
if err != nil {
  // good connection
}
```

I would like to preserve the **conn** value for later on verifying if the connection is active. I dont want to re-connect from time to time to check the connection as it causes various TIME_WAITs on the OS, so overall my requirements are:

- create a connection
- preserve the connection object
- capture if the connection drops for any reason
- **do not send or receive any data**

Any thoughts on how to achieve this ? Is there a way to capture that the connection is discontinued without sending or receiving data or reconnecting ?

Comment: A connection is only "active" if it's being used. You maintain the connection state by using it, and you detect a closed connection by reading from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to do without performing an operation. If it is infrequently used, when you try to read you may get an error if the client (or some proxy) closed the connection. If that happens then reconnect and retry.

Many protocols will bake in a heartbeat mechanism to facilitate this kind of thing. Then you can read constantly (with SetDeadline if you want) and know within a heartbeat frame that something went wrong.

For example, I use a redis client that supports connection pooling. When I retrieve an idele connection from the pool, I immediately perform a PING operation. If that succeeds, I know the connection is ready to use. If not, I get another idle one, or connect anew.